# Whats wrong with my function?

Tags: function, scanf, frequency

My char read function isnt working, it prints what i would like it to print but it prevents the program from going to the next step and and reading what number the user inputted, it worked fine before it was a function but i need it to have a certain amount of functions as this is an assignment

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int length();
float mtof( int note);
float octave(int notes);
char read(char print);


int main()
{
    //do while the user hasnt pressed exit key (whatever)
    int control[8] = {74, 71, 91, 93, 73, 72, 5, 84};
    int index;
    int mod;
    float frequency;
    int notes[8];
    int response;
    float octave;
    char print;

    mod = aserveGetControl(1);




    //ask backwards, forwards, exit

    //SCALING
    //(getControl(75) / ((127 - 0) / (1000 - 100))) + 100;
    while(true)
    {
        read(print);
        mod = 0;
        if(response == 1)

        {
            while(mod==0)
            {
                for(index = 0; index < 8; index++)
                {
                    notes[index] = aserveGetControl(control[index]);
                    frequency = mtof(notes[index]);
                    aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
                    aserveSleep(length());
                    printf("Slider Value:%5d\n", notes[index]);
                    printf("frequency: %f\n", frequency);
                    mod = aserveGetControl(1);
                    octave = aserveGetControl(7);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(response == 2)
        {
            while(mod==0)
            {
                for(index = 7; index > 0; index--)
                {
                    notes[index] = aserveGetControl(control[index]);
                    frequency = mtof(notes[index]);
                    aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
                    aserveSleep(length());
                    printf("Slider Value:%5d\n", notes[index]);
                    printf("%f", frequency);
                    mod = aserveGetControl(1);

                }
            }

        }
        else if(response == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
int length()
{
    return (aserveGetControl(75)/((127.0 - 0) / (1000 - 100))) + 100;
}

float mtof( int note)
{
    return 440 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
}
float octave(int note)
{
    float slider = aserveGetControl(7) / 16383.0;
    slider *=24;
    return 440 * pow(2, ((note+slider)-69) / 12.0);
}
char read(char print)
{
    char response;
    printf("Run Loop Forwards (1), Backwards (2), Exit (0)\nMove modwheel to return to menu\n");
    scanf("%c", &response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return response from read:

```
char read(char print)
{
    char response;
    printf("Run Loop Forwards (1), Backwards (2), Exit (0)\nMove modwheel to return to  menu\n");
    scanf("%c", &response);
    return response;
}
```

and you need to assign it in the main path of your code:

```
response = read(print);
```

I'd like to point out that you should really declare response as a char since that is what you are returning from read. Also, I can't see print being used anywhere so I'm not sure of the purpose of passing it to read.